# $\exists$ countably generated $\mathcal F$, s.t. $\sigma(\{ \{\omega \}: \omega\in\Omega \}) \subsetneqq \mathcal F \subsetneqq \mathcal B(\Omega)$?

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Does there exist a countably generated $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$ on a [second countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) $\Omega$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  \sigma(\{ \{\omega \}: \omega\in\Omega \}) \subsetneqq \mathcal F \subsetneqq \mathcal B(\Omega)?
\end{equation*}

---

Here is the motivation, also some clues.

One the one hand, since $\Omega$ is second countable, its Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal B(\Omega)$ is clearly countably generated (by a countable topological base). But the $\sigma$-field generated by singletons $\sigma(\{ \{\omega \}: \omega\in\Omega \})$ is just the countable co-countable $\sigma$-field, which is [not countably generated in general, say e.g., when $\Omega=\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579212/generating-set-of-countable-co-countable-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr/1580493).

On the other hand, [$\sigma(\{ \{\omega \}: \omega\in\Omega \})$ is countably generated if and only if $\Omega$ is itself a countable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2851928/hint-on-simple-problem-regarding-countably-generated-sigma-algebras). In this case, $\sigma(\{ \{\omega \}: \omega\in\Omega \})$ coincides with $\mathcal B(\Omega)$, and there is no such intermediate $\mathcal F$.

So does such intermediate $\mathcal F$  exist in some general cases? Or it definitely does not exist whenever the second countable space $\Omega$ is?

---

Any comments or hints will be appreciated. TIA...

---

**EDIT:** There should be some appropriate examples for the intermediate $\mathcal F$, as shown in the comment by @bof and the answer by @Henno Brandsma. But what happens if we force $\Omega$ to be a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), which is stronger and more commonly used in measure theory than second countable space? I think then there will be no such intermediate $\mathcal F$, but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question so maybe this is nonsense, but what if $\Omega$ is the set of real numbers with a second countable topology strictly finer than the usual topology, say the topology generated by the usual open sets plus some random non-Borel set? Then wouldn't the usual Borel sets serve as the intermediate $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @bof Thank you. Okay, you get the point. This is a good example. The second countable condition is much wide in the content of measure theory after all. How about the case that $\Omega$ is a Polish space? I think then there is no such intermediate $\mathcal F$ but I don't know how to prove. Anyway, Thank you for the comment.

Comment: But Henno Brandsma's examples can't work, because the space of irrational numbers is a Polish space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a theorem of Blackwell

*Blackwell, David*, On a class of probability spaces, Proc. 3rd Berkeley Sympos. Math. Statist. Probability 2, 1-6 (1956). [ZBL0073.12301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0073.12301).

> Let $(A,\mathscr A)$ be an analytic measurable space, and let $\mathscr A_0$ be a countably-generated sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathscr A$.  Then a subset of $A$
> belongs to $\mathscr A_0$ if and only if it belongs to $\mathscr A$ and is the union
> of a family of atoms of $\mathscr A_0$.

A special case of an analytic measurable space is a Polish space with its Borel sets.  If $\{x\} \in \mathcal A_0$ for all $x$, then the condition "is the union
of a family of atoms of $\mathscr A_0$" holds for all sets.  So in
that case $\mathscr A_0 = \mathscr A$.

---

This is Theorem 8.6.7 on page 291 of the text

*Cohn, Donald L.*, Measure theory, Boston, Basel, Stuttgart: Birkhäuser (1980). [ZBL0436.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0436.28001).

Comment: Very nice. I read that paper, and that's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, where in the paper is that result? I cannot seem to find it

Answer (score 0):

A candidate is taking $\Omega$ to be the irrationals (as a subspace of the reals) and as $\mathcal{F}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact subsets of $\Omega$. This is clearly an in-between $\sigma$-field (finite sets are compact and compact sets are closed so Borel) but I think it might not be countably generated ($\Omega$ and its open subsets are all not $\sigma$-compact).. Throwing it out as my first impulse... Maybe I'll get better ideas later. Similar and probably not countably generated either: the Borel zero-sets (and their complements) for a given Borel measure, or the first category Borel sets (and their complements) in a Baire space (to avoid degeneration)..

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I am trying to prove that there is no such in-between $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$ when $\Omega$ is a Polish space, as I believe it is true. Please also think about it, because the Polish space assumption is more common in measure/probability theory. Thank you.

Comment: @Dreamer what would be the use of knowing this fact for Polish spaces? We usually only consider the Borel algebra on it anyway.

Comment: Remark: the irrationals is a Polish space.  So Henno thinks the $\mathcal F$ constructed here is probably not countably generated.