# Does every σ-algebra contain a minimal countably generated one containing the singletons?

Tags: measure-theory

I just learned through [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834480/exists-countably-generated-mathcal-f-s-t-sigma-omega-omega) that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Polish space is minimal among countably generated $\sigma$-algebras containing all singletons.

This raises the following question:

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal A$ be a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra
of subsets of $X$, containing all singletons $\{x\}$, for $x$ in $X$.  Can we always find a minimal sub-$\sigma$-algebra
of $\mathcal A$ satisfying these same two properties, namely countably generated and containing all singletons?

If not, can one formulate
sensible sufficient hypotheses for this to hold?

Comment: What do you mean by a second-countable $\sigma$-algebra?  One that is generated by a countable set?

Comment: @EricWofsey, sorry, will edit to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" for silly reasons:

1. Not all $\sigma$-algebras contain all singletons. For example, take the indiscrete $\sigma$-algebra on any set with more than $1$ element. This does not contain any singletons, and therefore does not contain any countably generated sub-$\sigma$-algebras which contain all singletons.
2. Any countably generated $\sigma$-algebra has cardinality $\leq \mathfrak{c}$ (the continuum). Thus, if $X$ is any set of cardinality $> \mathfrak{c}$ (e.g. the power set of $\mathbb{R}$), there can be no countably generated $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ which contain all singletons.

I'm not sure how to tell when there *will* be such a minimal countably generated $\sigma$-algebra, but I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: @bof OP edited their question to clarify that, to them, "second countable $\sigma$-algebra" means "countably generated $\sigma$-algebra". I also had not seen this terminology before. I also agree that, by standard definitions, all Polish spaces are second-countable (by virtue of being separable and metrizable). For the record, I'm also unfamiliar with the result OP cited. However, OP's question was unambiguous (if confusingly phrased), so I tried to answer what part of it I could.

Comment: @bof,  I hope the question is better worded now.  I apologize for typing my question the first time on a cellphone where the limited editing tools does take a toll on one's  other brain functions.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, I am sorry for the poorly worded initial formulation of my question but I hope it is better now.  My intention in editing it was not to invalidate your answers, which were both helpful to help me  focus on the more substantive aspect of the question.